# Angular - cannot access variable inside Jquery click function

Tags: jquery, angular, devextreme

i have below DataGrid columns cellTemplate coded as :

```
ctAccount(cellElement, cellInfo) {
 $('<div>')
      .appendTo(cellElement)
      .text(cellInfo.data.Other)
      .css('cursor', 'pointer')
      .on('click', function(event) {
             this.dDetail["aaa"] = { store: AspNetData.createStore({
                                                  key: "ID",
                                                  loadParams: { id: cellInfo.data.GroupID },
                                                  loadUrl: this.Svr.urlSuspect + "Group" 
                                              })
                                      };
       ...                      
       ...
```

the problem is 'this' (this.dDetail, this.Svr) is not access by the compiler, because 'this' is referring to 'this: HTMLElement', not refer to my angular project. Error message is

property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

How can i code on this.dDetail and this.Svr ?

Answer (score 0):

Store the `this` reference in a variable at the correct scope, then use that variable within the `click` handler function:

```js
ctAccount(cellElement, cellInfo) {
  let _this = this;
  $('<div>')
    .appendTo(cellElement)
    .text(cellInfo.data.Other)
    .css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .on('click', function(event) {
      _this.dDetail["aaa"] = {
        store: AspNetData.createStore({
          key: "ID",
          loadParams: {
            id: cellInfo.data.GroupID
          },
          loadUrl: _this.Svr.urlSuspect + "Group"
        })
      };
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: i try 2 solution but compile no problem, run time error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dDetail' of undefined

Comment: In which case it sounds like you're expecting `this` to be an even higher scope than the `ctAccount()` function. Use the same approach as outlined in this answer, but just define `_this` in the right place for the code you've got.

Comment: i try to add in beginning : export class xxxComponent implements OnInit {
  _this = this;   but no effect ! now the error is : cannot find name '_this'

Comment: You forgot the `var` (or `let` if you're supporting ES6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 `arrow functions`.

Like

```
ctAccount(cellElement, cellInfo) {

  .on('click', (event) => {
         this.dDetail["aaa"] = { store: AspNetData.createStore({
```